# Unable to load software sources, software & updates in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: software-sources

Having trouble getting any of the above to run. I've tried various upgrade and reinstall suggestions from other forums but with no luck. Software updater claims everything is up to date, but I can't open the settings from there either.

When i try to manually start the software-properties-gtk in terminal i get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/usr/bin/software-properties-gtk", line 101, in <module>
    app = SoftwarePropertiesGtk(datadir=options.data_dir, options=options, file=file)   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/gtk/SoftwarePropertiesGtk.py", line 98, in __init__
    SoftwareProperties.__init__(self, options=options, datadir=datadir)   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 109, in __init__
    self.reload_sourceslist()   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 599, in reload_sourceslist
    self.distro.get_sources(self.sourceslist)       File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptsources/distro.py", line 89, in get_sources
    (self.id, self.codename)) aptsources.distro.NoDistroTemplateException: Error: could not find a distribution template for Ubuntu/n/a
```

It's worth pointing out that I can still install/remove software using apt-get or the software center.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance for any help.

Craig

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a problem with your software sources. Press `Alt+f2` on your keyboard and write following code

```
    software-properties-gtk
```

Then in the `Ubuntu Software` tab change the `Download from` setting. Change to `Main Server` if using any local server. See if it works.

If the above answer doesn't solve the error, open a terminal and run following code

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
```

It should solve the error.

Another option is to update `/etc/lsb-release` file according to your installation, for example

```
    DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
    DISTRIB_RELEASE=14.04
    DISTRIB_CODENAME=trusty
    DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 14.04"
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, however running software-properties-gtk from the alt-f2 prompt doesn't seem to do anything. I suspect the same error is happening, just that there isn't any feedback like there is in the terminal? According to the terminal, software-properties-terminal is already up to date, i've tried removing then reinstalling it but with no luck.

Comment: I should add, the icon for software proerties does appear in the search, but the window doesn't open, so i'm not able to seee any tabs etc

Comment: Check the third option

Comment: that was it! /etc/lsb-release wasn't there! copied a backup file to it and it fixed everything instantly. Thanks very much!